# Create a automated transfer after clicking 4 images

Tags: javascript

As the title say I have a row of 4 pictures. When I click on them they will change to another one. When all 4 pictures have changed I want the function to transfer me to a new URL.
This has to be in javascript.

This is how far I have gotten:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="datemedmig.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Uppgift B</title>
        <script>
            function changePic1 (guy1) 
            { 
                document.getElementById("guy1").src ="1b.jpg"; 
            }

            function changePic2 (guy2) 
            { 
                document.getElementById("guy2").src ="2b.jpg";
            }

            function changePic3 (guy3) 
            { 
                document.getElementById("guy3").src ="3b.jpg"; 
            }

            function changePic4 (guy4) 
            { 
                document.getElementById("guy4").src ="4b.jpg";      
            }
        </script>
        <img id="guy1" src="1a.jpg" onclick=changePic1(this.name)>
        <img id="guy2" src="2a.jpg" onclick=changePic2(this.name)>
        <img id="guy3" src="3a.jpg" onclick=changePic3(this.name)>
        <img id="guy4" src="4a.jpg" onclick=changePic4(this.name)>
    </head>
</html>
```

Any help to would be appreciated!

Best regards 
A lost boy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [false, false, false, false];
function save(index){
  arr[index] = true;
  if(arr.filter(function(item){ return !item; }).length == 0) 
    location.href = "YOUR_HREF";
}

function changePic1 (guy1) 
        { 
            document.getElementById("guy1").src ="1b.jpg";
            save(0); 
        }

function changePic2 (guy2) 
{ 
            document.getElementById("guy2").src ="2b.jpg";
            save(1);
}

function changePic3 (guy3) 
{ 
      document.getElementById("guy3").src ="3b.jpg";  
      save(2);
}
function changePic4 (guy4) 
{ 
      document.getElementById("guy4").src ="4b.jpg";      
      save(3);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for a fast respons and it works perfect!

Comment: @user3310985 if my answer is right can you choose it?

Comment: Ah, yes! Im new here just found it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `boolean` flag for each image to switch when the image has been clicked an thus changed. When you click an image, check if all 4 flags are `true` and if yes, use `location.href` to redirect to your new URL.